# SQL Server Agent fails to start

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

I am replacing a SQL Server 2012 cluster with a new one (keeping the same version of SQL, changing OS from 2008R2 to 2012R2).
I have 1 node installed so far, but the agent won't start.  The error message is:
unable to connect to server '(local)'; sqlserveragent cannot start

The steps I have taken:
Stop SQL services on existing cluster
Move system databases
Unmap drives from old cluster
Setup new cluster using same drives
Install SQL server.
Stop SQL services
Replace system databases with original ones.
Star SQL services

The above all worked fine. But the agent won't start.  Am I being reall special?

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Alex

Comment: did you add an alias to the instance in the SQL Server Agent Configuration? 
The alias has to defined using the fully qualified domain name of the server. Example:servername.domain\instance_name otherwise the agent will still error out and shutdown. and re-enable agent too                                     "sp_configure 'Agent XPs', 1
go

reconfigure with override
go"

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to move the system DBs?  And, can you confirm its the same version of SQL, including SPs/CUs?  Technically you can move system DBs if it's the same exact version, but I wouldn't recommend this.  Instead I would recommend building a repeatable migration process, which includes transferring logins, jobs, linked servers, options, etc.  Alternatively you could us something like https://dbatools.io/, which is very handy.

Comment: Is this a traditional Failover Cluster or AlwaysOn? If it's a Failover Cluster the SQL Agent Service needs to be configured and run within the Failover Cluster Manager.